# Send dynamic text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to find a solution to send a text (that I write) from an input text to my JavaScript code below using jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pay").on('click', function() {
        var MYTEXT = $(this).attr('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "panier.php",
            data: "action=addpayement&typepay=" + typepay + "",
            success: function (msg) { 

            }   //  success
        }); 
    }); // end
});
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<input value="" type="text" id="pay" />
```

An ideas? (like this the script doesn't work)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pay").on('click', function() 
    {
        var MYTEXT= $('#MYTEXT').val();
        $.ajax({                                            
            type: "POST",
            url: "panier.php",
            data: "action=addpayement&typepay=" + MYTEXT + "",
            success: function(msg){    


            }   //  success
        }); 

    }); // end
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `#` to target element by `id` as well as using `.val()` to get the value of textbox(*or better* apply pure javascript using `this.value`). You also need to use `MYTEXT` instead of `typepay` since your variable name is `typepay`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pay").on('click', function () {
        var MYTEXT = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "panier.php",
            data: "action=addpayement&typepay=" + MYTEXT + "",
            success: function (msg) {

            } //  success
        });

    }); // end
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use val(),

```
 var MYTEXT = $(this).val();
```

thanks